# How can I call collectstatic routine inside a django app?

Tags: django, collectstatic

My Django app works with css/html themes and I can upload new themes from the user interface, that is, a regular user can upload a new theme without asking for a IT guy. I usually call a os.run('python manage.py collectstatic') but I would like to know if it is possible to do it in a more elegant or pythonic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`call_command(...)`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) as,

```
from django.core import management

management.call_command("collectstatic")
```